# mysql table names case sensitive

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

I have one website running on development server, over there I can execute query like,

```
SELECT * FROM Agents;
OR
SELECT * FROM agents;
```

I mean, It runs in both conditions. But, In my production server, it's giving me error.
What should I do to overcome this problem. Because I have used uppercase and lowercase in my php scripts, EVERYWHERE.

ERROR:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[42S02]:
Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'database_name.Agents' doesn't exist'
```

Comment: What error is MySQL giving you?

Comment: Try adding `lower_case_table_names=1` in `/etc/my.cnf`. This will make all your tables lowercase, no matter how you write them

Comment: If i will convert it to lower case. then I won't be able to access them with upper case. And in php script I used both cases.

Comment: be consistent in your naming, problem solved

Comment: At this point I can not change. It'll be huge change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to edit `/etc/my.cnf` and set [**lower_case_table_names** server variable](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/identifier-case-sensitivity.html).

- Open MySQL configuration file: `/etc/my.cnf`
- Look up for: `[mysqld]` section
- Add: lower_case_table_names = 2
- Save and restart MySQL service: `/etc/init.d/mysql restart`

If **lower_case_table_names** set to 0, table names are stored as specified and comparisons are case sensitive. If set to 1, table names are stored in lowercase on disk and comparisons are not case sensitive. **If set to 2, table names are stored as given but compared in lowercase**. This option also applies to database names and table aliases.

Answer (score 0):

Is your development server on Windows or Mac? Mysql on linux has case sensitive table names by default while Windows and Mac don't. For best compatibility between all systems, I recommend keeping your casing always consistent.

Unfortunately, I would advise you to fix it in ALL your scripts. If you can disable case sensitivity on your production server, that would be great, but if you ever migrate to a different system or work on a system where you cannot control the production settings, it is best coding practices to assume it will be case sensitive.

Comment: My server is on linux (centOS). And I am working from mac and windows.

Comment: http://vasir.net/blog/ubuntu/replace_string_in_multiple_files or find and replace all files in your favorite IDE. You really should just fix it.